# EXE throws errors when DEBUG does not

Tags: c#, .net, exception, visual-studio-debugging

The program has a form that pops up, you enter text in a few fields, then press close. Upon close the information entered is saved to a class `newItem`.

When I press F5 to debug  my program everything works fine. But when I run the executable from my debug folder I get this error.

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
    At.... line 168
```

Here's the code.

```
if (!LoadedItem.Contains(newItem))
{
    LoadedItem.Add(newItem);
}
```

I placed a break point, stepped through the code, everything seems to go as it should. It skips over if `LoadedItem` already has `newItem` in it. But for some reason it appears to ignore the if statement in the .exe.

Please let me know if there is more information you require.

I would appreciate any help, for the life of me I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: are you doing multithreading?

Comment: Do you have custom operators defined for the type of newItem?

Comment: Yes i am doing multithreading, and yes i have custom operators for newItem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by you have custom operators but it sounds like you are having multiple threads the same adding to LoadItem at the same time. Try locking it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx

Comment: Locking it did not work, but thank you anyways.

Answer (score 3):

Lock `LoadedItem` should work

```
lock(LoadedItem) {
    if (!LoadedItem.Contains(newItem))
       LoadedItem.Add(newItem);
}
```

Note that you have to use lock on every point in the code where you write and read to/from LoadedItem.

If you read more than write, use [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) to better performance.

If you're using .Net4 you can use some of the collections in the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace.

Comment: An option to avoid locking in your own code is to use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)

Comment: LoadedItem was used more than i thought, quite a large project. But locking them all didnt work, and I do not have 4.5 so no ConcurrentDicttionary. It just avoids the if statement. Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: After much trial and error what worked was a foreach checking items name against newitem.Name and setting a bool to true, and if false run the code... ugly

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a threading problem.  Make sure LoadedItem and NewItem are locally bound variables, so the two references are guaranteed to be the same object.

For debugging purposes, Replace "Contains" and "Add" with a wrapper functions whose behavior you can investigate.